# How to create a comments page in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, comments, uilabel, uitextview

I'm trying to create a comments page and I'm using UITextView for the space to add comments and UILabel for where the comments get printed. I'm wondering how I can make the comments "stick" on the page? Currently it keeps getting rewritten every time something new is entered in the UITextView. Thanks very much!

EDIT2:

Here's my code... do I need to store the data on some server or something?

In my header file:

```
{
    IBOutlet UITextView *commentBox;

    IBOutlet UILabel *commentsDisplay;


}

-(IBAction)submit;
```

In my implementation file:

```
 -(IBAction)submit{

   NSMutableString *tmpStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:commentsDisplay.text];
   [tmpStr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commentBox.text]];
   [commentsDisplay setText:tmpStr];

    commentBox.text = @"";

   [commentBox resignFirstResponder];

    }
```

Comment: post your code, let's see where is your bug. how do you expect for help without posting your code?

Comment: @TeodorCarstea just posted my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My starting suggestion is, don't use a view (UILabel) as the main storage location for data.

Create a `NSMutableString` property to hold comments (or maybe a `NSMutableArray` of strings) and, whenever there's a submit action, add the new string to what you had previously...then display that.  If you use a single string for this, look at `appendString:`.  If you go with an array, then add the new entry as an object in the array.  (I like the array idea because it would allow for choosing how many comments to display.)

Simply doing that should make the screen update look more like what you want and having the data separate from the screen elements makes it easier to save between launches of your app if you plan on doing that.

Comment: I kinda get what you're saying but I'm not sure how to display that. (I'm a complete newbie, sorry about that!) Do you mind showing an example of how that would work? Thanks very very much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
commentsDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[commentBox text]];
```

do this:

```
NSMutableString *tmpStr = [[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:commentsDisplay.text]autorelease];
[tmpStr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@", commentBox.text]];
[commentsDisplay setText:tmpStr];
```

This way you will append your submitted text to the existing one...

... and don't forget to make your label to be a multiline one (you can make this settings in Interface Builder).

Comment: Just edited it. Took out the autorelease cos' my version of Xcode4 doesn't allow it.